# rails 6 token authentication still needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csrf, ruby-on-rails-6, authenticity-token

I take courses on rails 5.x.x and when they used form they add a line for token authentication to protect their site, on the start of the form, like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
```

But to be on the last version of rails i'm on 6.1.3 version and i don't see anything on the web about that.
So the question is : Did I still need to set this authenticity token anywhere ? if yes, where ? and if no, why ? If you have some links about that for rails 6 I don't say no. Thank's you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to add it manually, Rails does it for you in each form.

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
  Form contents
<% end %>
```

generates

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="post">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="J7CBxfHalt49OSHp27hblqK20c9PgwJ108nDHX/8Cts=" />
  Form contents
</form>
```

> You'll notice that the HTML contains an input element with type
> hidden. This input is important, because non-GET forms cannot be
> successfully submitted without it. The hidden input element with the
> name authenticity_token is a security feature of Rails called
> cross-site request forgery protection, and form helpers generate it
> for every non-GET form (provided that this security feature is
> enabled). You can read more about this in the Securing Rails
> Applications guide.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html